# MVC3 Razor: Displaying html within code blocks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my cshtml files I have a lot of blocks with stuff like this:

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
    <span>Hello World</span>
}
```

The only reason the span is there is because I can't find any other way to force it to recognize that "Hello World" is part of the html unless I surround it in html tags. Is there a good way to escape the code that doesn't involve adding meaningless tags to the display?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You could use `@:` to escape:

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
    @:Hello World
}
```

or the special `<text>` tag which is not outputted in the response:

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
    <text>Hello World</text>
}
```

Comment: The second way (using <text>) is much better.  If you use @: Razor has a habit of losing your indentation, or even worse of adding extra spaces in HMTL tags (eg <div> becomes < div >), hence stopping your page working properly.  I've learnt this lesson slowly and painfully - avoid @:!

Comment: If anyone is struggling with this, note that the brackets "{ }" are mandatory...

Answer (score 15):

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
  @:Hello World
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add text in as below:

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
    @:Hello World
}
```

when you use `@` razor switch it to code block mode. Hence you need to specify text as above.

Answer (score 10):

```
<text>Explicit HTML<text>

@(Explicit C#)
```

Answer (score 8):

many developers has provided many ways above .. here is one more which is working fine in MVC 4 .. I hope it will work for MVC 3 also ..

```
@if(Model.foo)
{
    @Html.Label("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are great.  I'm going to include a link to Scott Guthrie's article on this, since it shows some more examples and explanations.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

```html
@if (p.UnitsInStock == 0 {
  <text>
    Donec in ante vitae purus consequat laoreet ut elementum
    purus. Ut ut tempus nulla, quis ultrices est. Integer
    pharetra ante in lectus porta, a lacinia ex faucibus. 
    Aliquam magna risus, pretium vel neque at, laoreet 
    ultrices lectus. Morbi posuere luctus risus. Nullam 
    tincidunt massa egestas nunc tempor scelerisque.  
  </text>
}


@if (p.UnitsInStock == 0 {
  @: Line 1
  @: Line 2
  @: Line 3
}
```