# ASP.NET MVC and Razor to display integer or blank when 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

If I have an integer value that I want to display on a page, I can do that a number of ways:

```
<span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)</span>
<span>@item.UserId</span>
```

But what is the best way to convert that to displaying the value IF UserId != 0.  But if UserId == 0, display an empty string.  Is there a way to do it right in Razor syntax or do I need to head to code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<span>@((item.UserID == 0) ? "" : @item.UserID.ToString())</span>
```

OR

```
<span>@if(item.UserID == 0) { <span></span> }
   else { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserID); }
</span>
```

I think you could do this with one `if` condition

```
<span>@if(item.UserID != 0) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserID); } //the browser would render empty string by itself
```

To render content without putting the redundant (as you said) `<span>`, use the `@:` - [MVC3 Razor: Displaying html within code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602419/mvc3-razor-displaying-html-within-code-blocks) and [@: for displaying content](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

```
<span>
   @if(item.UserID == 0) {  } //this is redundant too
   else { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserID); 
   }
</span>
```

Note that I have moved the `}` to next line. ASP.Net MVC did not accept it

```
<span>
   @if(item.UserID == 0) { @:Some content with no html tag wrapper 
   }
   else { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserID); 
   }
</span>
```

Comment: I like that you provided two examples, the first one more inline and the second with the if/else block.  But in the if/else block example, how to get away from adding an additional/redundant empty span tag?

Comment: Thank you codingbiz.  The number of examples has given me a better understanding of Razor.

Answer (score 10):

Create an extension method for int:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static string EmptyIfZero(this int value)
    {
        if(value == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

... and then in your Razor view, do:

```
<span>@item.UserId.EmptyIfZero()</span>
```

Comment: I like this too.  I reusable option.

Comment: this should be accepted as answer because of reusablity

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

`<span>@(item.UserId != 0 ? item.UserId.ToString() : string.Empty)</span>`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and most reusable would be to create a template.

So you create e.g. `UserId.vbhtml` in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`
with the following content:

in the template you build all the logic, which would be something like (I am typing without checking and I usually code in VB, so there may be mistakes):

```
@model int
@((Model == 0) ? "" : @Model)
```

And then in the code you use:
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId, "UserId")`

You can also put UIHint attribute over UserId in your class: `[UIHint("UserId")]`
and then you do not need to provide the template name.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to display **integer** or **blank** when model value is **0**.

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "User Id")]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<span>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserId)
</span>
<span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { @Value = (Model.UserId > 0 ? Model.UserId.ToString() : string.Empty) })
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some more global solution, display blank for:
- integer: 0
- decimal: 0.0
- string: "0x0" or "0x0x0"

Extension class:

```
public static class DataTypesExtension
{
    static string[] Keywords = { "0", "0.0", "0.00", "0.000", "0.0000", "0,0", "0,00", "0,000", "0,0000", "0x0", "0x0x0" };
    public static string BlankIfZero(this object n)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;

        if (n == null)
            return ret;

        string sn = n.ToString().Replace(" ", "");


        if (!DataTypesExtension.Keywords.Contains(sn))
            ret = n.ToString();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Display template:

```
@model object

@using MyProject.Extensions;

@{
    string val = Model.BlankIfZero();
    @val;        
}
```

And in View Model:

```
[UIHint("BlankIfZero")]
public int? MyIntProperty { get; set; }

[UIHint("BlankIfZero")]
public decimal? MyDecimalProperty { get; set; }

[UIHint("BlankIfZero")]
public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

On my case, i found this to be easier:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myField").val("");
}
```

Not sure if this is wahat you were looking for, but worked fine for me.

Comment: The problem here is that if the server returns a validation error the page will refresh with the errors listed and your field will again be blank, even if the user had entered a value...