# proper razor syntax for switch statement inside foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a heck of a time trying to find the proper syntax for creating a switch statement inside a foreach loop on my mvc view page.

Here is the latest attempt (after many others) I have so far but the the Razor engine won't accept it. Here the error is right at the `@foreach` and indicates it is missing a closing `}`

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    String s = item.RegistrationStatus.ToString();

    // Make sure this mirrors values in RegistrationStatus enum!
    switch (s)
    {
        case "New": 
            <tr class='info'>
                break;

        case "Arrived": 
            <tr class='success'>
            break;

        default:
            <tr>

    }


......

}
```

Comment: The most likely reason it's not working for you is that Razor can only do its automatic C#/HTML detection when tags are well-formed and closed. If you want only an open tag, you have to use the "@:<foo>" syntax that the other responders have shown.

Comment: It is just a personal thing, but I stopped using switch statements in Views a while ago since it really messes up readability. A helper method would be better imo. On a side note, it is also better to use something like `Html.Raw` or `MvcHtmlString.Create` because Razor might be throwing warnings because it cannot find closing tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do as Justin suggests, something in the way of this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    String s = item.RegistrationStatus.ToString();

    // Make sure this mirrors values in RegistrationStatus enum!
    switch (s)
    {
        case "New":
            @:<tr class='info'>
            break;

        case "Arrived":
            @:<tr class='success'>
            break;

        default:
            @:<tr>
            break;
    }

    ......
}
```

But, if you're running [MVC4 with Razor V2](http://blog.sigma.se/en/Development/Mario-Ienasescu/Dates/2012/4/Whats-new-in-Razor-for-ASPNET-MVC4/), you could as easily use a helper method (or regular method) instead:

```
public static class MyHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetCssClass(this HtmlHelper helper, RegistrationStatus status)
    {
        // Make sure this mirrors values in RegistrationStatus enum!
        switch (status)
        {
            case RegistrationStatus.New:
                return "info";

            case RegistrationStatus.Arrived:
                return "success";

            default:
                return null; // Return null so that the attribute won't render.
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{    
    <tr class='@Html.GetCssClass(item.RegistrationStatus)'>

    .....
}
```

This is a bit more readable and easier to maintain. If the GetCssClass() method returns `null` then Razor V2 won't even render the attribute (in this case `class=`).

Comment: What is the best folder to place the MyHelperExtensions file ?  Thanks!

Comment: @ChiliYago I usually create a folder called *Helpers* or *Extensions* in the root. Also don't forget to add the namespace for the `MyHelperExtensions` class in *Views\Web.config* -> `<configuration><system.web.webPages.razor><pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"><namespaces>` so that it shows up automatically in your views.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Html.Raw method:

```
    case "New": 
        Html.Raw("<tr class='info'>")
        break;
```

Also see [MVC3 Razor: Displaying html within code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602419/mvc3-razor-displaying-html-within-code-blocks) for other options such as:

```
    case "New": 
       @:<tr class='info'>
       break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to use { in a separate line. With that approach you get more lines of code. On the other hand, you get clear lines of html tags without "@:" garbage. That allows you quickly copy-paste entire html lines "as is" from/to a real html during "in-browser" debugging.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    String s = item.RegistrationStatus.ToString();

    // Make sure this mirrors values in RegistrationStatus enum!
    switch (s)
    {
        case "New":
        {
            <tr class='info'>
        }
            break;
        case "Arrived":
        {
            <tr class='success'>
        }
            break;
        default:
        {
            <tr>
        }
            break;
    }

......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant for ASP NET CORE 2.2 MVC

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    String s = item.RegistrationStatus.ToString();

    // Make sure this mirrors values in RegistrationStatus enum!
    switch (s)
    {
        case "New":
            @Html.Raw("<tr class='info'>")
            break;

        case "Arrived":
            @Html.Raw("<tr class='success'>")
            break;

        default:
            @Html.Raw("<tr>")
            break;
    }

    ......
    @Html.Raw("/<tr>")
}
```

Comment: This is insufficient as an answer.