# Avoid wrapping something in HTML tags within a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 I constantly have to wrap my C# output code in an HTML tag to prevent .NET from throwing an error. It's easier to explain by showing, so here's the code:

```
<li onclick="alert('@pub.URL');" data-jstree='{"icon":"@Url.Content("~/Images/blue-folder.png")"}'>
  @if (pub.DescriptionLongerThan50Chars)
  {
     pub.DescriptionCropped
  }
  else
  {
     //
  }
</li>
```

This throws an "Only assignment, call, increment.." error to be thrown. The easy solution is the wrap `pub.DescriptionCropped` in a `<span>`, but if I don't have to do this I'd rather not.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 Razor: Displaying html within code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602419/mvc3-razor-displaying-html-within-code-blocks)

Comment: Yes I think it is. I did search but it seems I couldn't find the right terms.

Comment: I'm always trying to figure out if it's better to respond to a question (like the guys here) and get the reputation points, or point out a duplicate, and get nothing. But this is for the greater good of  SO.

Comment: Is it really? I couldn't find the topic you posted with my search terms. Hopefully someone in future will find this post with the search terms I was originally using. If Stackoverflow's purpose is to be a neat and tidy repository of threads then I'm wrong, but if its purpose is to help the greatest number of people then I think answering is better.

Comment: Well actually I think this decision belongs to the moderators, but my opinion is that SO should be neat and tidy. As you can see, I found the duplicate in under 3 minutes from the time you posted. It wasn't even hard, I searched for : `razor` `mvc` text node inside code tag and got the first link from google

Comment: Does me asking a question that's already been asked make this website "dirty" in some way? If so, the gods/mods might want to start deleting questions rather than just closing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to prepend your line with '@:`

```
< li onclick="alert('@pub.URL');" data-jstree='{"icon":"@Url.Content("~/Images/blue-     folder.png")"}'>

  @if (pub.DescriptionLongerThan50Chars)
  {
   @:pub.DescriptionCropped
  }
  else
  {
   //
  }
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can display plain text this way with razor:

```
@if (pub.DescriptionLongerThan50Chars)
  {
     @:pub.DescriptionCropped // now it is rendered as html
  }
  else
  {
     //
  }
```